# How to Add Missing Foundation Baselines in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

So Someone from my team has deleted some **foundation Baselines** from an **Integration Stream** and now when people rebase their development stream many of the folders and files inside them are missing.

We can see those missing foundation baselines in the development streams of that Integration Stream.

So I wanted to know how I can add those missing foundation Baselines from those dev stream to int stream, we only have access to **IBM ClearTeam explorer** to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> we only have access to IBM ClearTeam explorer to do it.

So you still have the [CCRC CLI (`rcleartool`)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.2?topic=server-installation-configuration-ccrc-cli) (assuming the CCRC WAN Server is upgraded to ClearCase® version 8.0.0.3 or higher)

[`mkbl`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/rational-clearcase/8.0.0?topic=ucm-mkbl), however, is a `cleartool` command only (not `rcleartool`) in CC8, but [`rcleartool mkbl`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/fr/rational-clearcase/9.0.2?topic=ucm-mkbl) does exist for CC 9.x.

You could use that to recreate your fundation baseline, assuming you can tweak a (preferable dynamic or webview) config spec to select the right versions.

Comment: I wanted to know whether existing baselines on a dev stream of the integration stream could  be readded to that  integration stream as the baselines were deleted from the integration stream.

Comment: If those baselines are full, not incremental, then you can use a dynamic view on the right integration stream, with a config spec modified to select the tag of the dev baseline, selecting the right version and create from there a new foundation baseline.

Comment: All that because you cannot directly rebate a su stream dev baseline on an integration parent stre.

Answer (score 0):

The baseline still exists, so you should be able to rebase the integration stream to re-add the baselines. You may want to describe the baseline to find the stream the baseline was created in to be sure you know everything you need to know about it.

rcleartool rebase -baseline baseline1@/vobs/mypvob,baseline2@/vobs/mypvob

Should be enough to accomplish the job. If your int stream has a successor baseline as the foundation now, and the component is not read-only in your project, you'll get an error message. The error message should tell you more about why you can't do the rebase.